# Constraint of a variable with an expression in nonlinear model fitting - independent variable constraint?

Tags: fitting, nonlinear

I am attempting to fit a set of experimental binding data:

```
data={{0.1, 0.127}, {0.142, 0.131}, {0.203, 0.163}, {0.289, 0.303}, {0.411,0.45}, {0.585, 0.648}, {0.833, 0.7}, {1.19, 1.02}, {1.69,1.1}, {2.4, 1.27}, {3.42, 1.44}, {4.87, 1.62}, {6.93, 1.69}, {9.87,1.85}, {14, 1.82}, {20, 1.87}}
```

with a nonlinear least squares model. The data is organized as a list of of lists with $(x_T,<x>) $ experimental measurements (in $\mu M$) where $x_T$ is the total ligand present and $<x>$ is the moles of ligand bound per moles of total protein.

I have tried searching through some previous forum posts as well as the [wolfram documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NonlinearModelFit.html)
but I am still having a little bit of trouble defining my model. Here is the model I would like to fit:

$$<x>\:= \frac{2k_1 x+2k_1 k_2x^2}{1+2k_1x+k_1k_2x^2} $$

where

$$x=\:x_T\: -<x> \times \: concentration$$ is the expression for x in the model. Is it possible to set it up such that x is represented implicitly in the model? My goal is to obtain parameter estimations for $k_1$ and $k_2$.

Here is the nonlinear model I currently have set up:

```
concentration = 1
indNonIdenticalModel := (2 k1 x + 2 k1 k2 x^2)/(1 + 2 k1 x + k1 k2 x^2)
nlm = NonlinearModelFit[data, indNonIdenticalModel, {k1, k2}, {x}]
```

This evaluates, but I'm not convinced my implementation is doing what I intend / expect it to be doing because I haven't supplied any information about the constraint for x. I also tried to use the syntax {model,{constraints}} but I'm not specifying conditional expressions such as x>5 so I didn't understand how I could implicitly define a constraint on x that is derived from the experimental data.

```
indNonIdenticalModel := (2 k1 x + 2 k1 k2 x^2)/(1 + 2 k1 x + k1 k2 x^2)
nlm = NonlinearModelFit[data, {indNonIdenticalModel, {x=}}{k1, k2}, {x}]
```

I apologize if I'm missing something painfully obvious here. I am relatively new to mathematica.

Heres an image of the agreement I have. It looks quite good but the constants are different than I expected when compared to another software (around k1=2.2*10^7 and k2= 8.7*10^5 M) [image: model fit]

**EDIT:**
I realize now why the models are getting vastly different parameter estimations, but I'm unsure how to resolve the issue mathematica is generating. Attached are some pictures. I think what I need to do is mandate the fit be valid across the independent variable range (lets say 0<x<20), but I tried to use the form from the documentation and couldn't constrain x.

```
nlmTest = NonlinearModelFit[data, {indNonIdenticalModel, {0 < x < 20}}, {n, k}, x]
```

[image: Mathematica Generated Fit from NonlinearModelFit]

[image: Known model fit: note the drop off at 0]
Here is the equation for the plot:

```
keyPlot =  Show[Plot[(44.` x + 38.279999999999994`x^2)/(1+44.`x+19.139999999999997` x^2), {x, 0, 20},PlotRange -> All]]
```

Comment: I'm not quite following the notation but it seems like you're trying to have the response variable $< x >$ on both sides of the equation.  Is that what you're trying to do?

Comment: Yeah. I believe so. Like in theory I could plug in the definition of x in the equation for the model and fit (I tried that and got a bunch of issues, and I don't think it'll extend well to even more complicated systems). So I instead would like to define a function that the NonLinearModelFit can recognize to exchange the definition of x. Does that help clarify?

Comment: If the response variable (call it y) is on both sides of the equation, then one could potentially solve for y (so that it's just on one side of the equation) using `sol = Solve[y == (2 k1 x + 2 k1 k2 x^2)/(1 + 2 k1 x + k1 k2 x^2) /. x -> xt - y, y];`.  But that does give an awfully complicated set of equations.

Comment: Yeah, that indeed get's quite quite ugly. Maybe there just isn't a simple solution to the problem I have.