# Nonlinear model fitting constraint problem

Tags: fitting

I have been having a great deal of difficulty understanding how to properly use the "NonlinearModelFit" functionality in Mathematica. I have scoured the documentation and online videos trying many different models. [see here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/240150/constraint-of-a-variable-with-an-expression-in-nonlinear-model-fitting-indepen). So instead I want to propose a simplified system and ask if such a design is possible in mathematica.

Suppose I want to calculate the parameters $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$ with the following constraints:

Independent variable: $x$

Dependent variables: $y_1,y_2$

Parameters: $\theta_1,\theta_2,\theta_3$

Constraints:

$y_2=x-y_1*\theta_3$

$y_1=\frac{\theta_1*\theta_2*y_2}{1+\theta_2*y_2}$

$0<y_1<\theta_1$

$0<y_2<x$

It may be that NonlinearModelFit is not suitable to handle the analysis I need to do (ideally it would be robust enough to fit an arbitary number of dependent variables, parameters, and constraints), but that isn't clear to me from the documentation I've read and examples I've seen. I am relatively new to mathematica so if such a thing is possible I'd appreciate any pointers.

Comment: What did you try so far? Please provide your Mathematica code and your data.

Comment: Sorry, I linked the post that addresses the actual problem that I am attempting to solve and the things I have tried. This is a a simplified model with arbitrary parameters to demonstrate the kind of analysis I would like to perform. This is more general to eliminate any jargon associated with the problem. I would like to know if it's possible to define these kinds of constraints in mathematica's implementation of' nonlinear least squares as it looks like you can only constrain the parameters from the documentation